# Why do my css animations become exponentially smaller and eventually stop working?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am making a small game where a block slides towards the character, and onclick of the main body of the game through a mouse, the character jumps to avoid the block. Whenever I refresh the page, it works normally, but after a few clicks the animation gets smaller and smaller (in the distance is jumps and the time it takes for the animation to complete) and eventually stops working completely. I have included a code snippet so you can see the problem.

```js
let character = document.getElementById('character');
let obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');
function jump() {
    if (character.classList != 'animate') {
        character.classList.add('animate');
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        character.classList.remove('animate');
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.game {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
@keyframes jump{
    0%{top: 150px;}
    30%{top: 100px;}
    70%{top: 100px;}
    100%{top: 150;}
}
.character {
    height: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
.animate {
    animation: jump 0.5s;
}
@keyframes block{
    0%{left: 480px;}
    100%{left: -40px;}
}
.obstacle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
    animation: block 2s  infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jumping Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jump.css">
</head>
<div>

    <body onclick="jump()">
        <div class="game">
            <div id="character" class="character">

            </div>
            <div id="obstacle" class="obstacle">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
<script src="jump.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing because you are using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: You add more and more *intervals*, that remove the animation. You have to use a *timeout*! (or, even better, an `animationend` event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `setInterval`, which executes the function provided to it repeatedly in 500ms intervals until you stop it with `clearInterval` (passing timeout id returned from initial `setInterval` call).

If you only want to execute the function once after 500ms, use `setTimeout` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/dp0n8Leh/ (making sure you first `clearTimeout` for the previous timeout, if you click early enough)

Also, to check if an element has a class, you should use `!character.classList.contains('animate')` instead of `character.classList != 'animate'`

Answer (score 0):

just use setTimeout not setInterval to remove the class